# Add SERVING meta tag to frozen model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

How is it possible to prepare a frozen Tensorflow model to serving? *Note that the [official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_inception#export_inception_model_in_container) only demonstrates how to use a checkpoint, but I'd like to use the frozen model.*

Using the [frozen inception_v3 model](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb.tar.gz) I'd like to add the [`SERVING`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/tag_constants.py#L27) meta tag, such [that the model can be used with Tensorflow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic#train_and_export_tensorflow_model).

Inspecting the frozen model `inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb` with [summarize_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#inspecting-graphs) the model input and output tensors can be found:

```
Found 1 possible inputs: (name=input, type=float(1), shape=[1,299,299,3])
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1, op=Reshape)
Found 23853946 (23.85M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 0 control_edges
Op types used: 489 Const, 379 Identity, 188 Mul, 188 Add, 95 Conv2D, 94 Sub, 94 Rsqrt, 94 Relu, 15 ConcatV2, 10 AvgPool, 4 MaxPool, 2 Reshape, 1 BiasAdd, 1 Softmax, 1 Squeeze, 1 Placeholder
To use with tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model try these arguments:
bazel run tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model -- --graph=assets/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb --show_flops --input_layer=input --input_layer_type=float --input_layer_shape=1,299,299,3 --output_layer=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Which yields the input tensor `input:0` and the output tensor `InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1:0`. In my script I use both of them to create a signature definition and save a so updated version.

```
model_path = './assets/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb'
target_dir = './models/inception/3'

with tf.gfile.FastGFile(model_path, 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

input_name = 'input'
output_name = 'InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1'

with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_input = build_tensor_info(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_name + ':0'))
    model_output = build_tensor_info(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_name + ':0'))

    signature_definition = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
        inputs={input_name: model_input},
        outputs={output_name: model_output},
        method_name=signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME)

    builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(target_dir)
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, [tag_constants.SERVING], signature_def_map={
        signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature_definition
    }, clear_devices=True)
    builder.save()
```

Unfortunately I cannot get the so created protobuffer file to work. The test tool [`label_image.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py) does not yield correct results, although it does work with the original `inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb` file.

```
$ python3 tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py --graph models/inception/3/saved_model.pb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py", line 118, in <module>
    graph = load_graph(model_file)
  File "tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py", line 31, in load_graph
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

But the tag is set

```
$ saved_model_cli show --dir models/inception/3
The given SavedModel contains the following tag-sets:
serve
```

What is wrong with the so changed frozen model? And how would this be done correctly?